# Is the following the valid ruby statement/expression

Tags: ruby

saw the following in some .rb file

```
 name "something"
```

why not using assignment like `name = "something"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
name = "something"
```

assigns `something` to a variable called `name`.

```
name "something"
```

calls the method `name` passing `something` as parameter.

They are two different statements.

Comment: actually, `name = "something"` would call the method `name=` with `"something"` as parameter.

Comment: No, `name = "something"` **never** calls the `name=()` method. That only happens with explicit receivers, for example `foo.name = "something"`.

Comment: As long as we are nitpicking: neither of the two are statements. There are no statements in Ruby, everything is an expression.